# IE Automation: How to click on div

Tags: html, vb.net, internet-explorer, automation

I'm new to vb.net and I'm trying to automate user login to a remote app on a website using vb.net. I have the login working but can't seem to figure out how to click on the div to start the app. Relevant code:

```
ie = CreateObject("internetExplorer.Application")
ie.visible = True
ie.Navigate("https://thesite/default.aspx")

Do
    If ie.ReadyState = 4 Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

This all works, but now I need to click on the div:

```
<div tabindex="0" title="myApp" class="tswa_boss" onmouseover="tswa_bossOver(this)" onmouseout="tswa_bossOut(this)" onmouseup="goRDP(this, huge block of encrypted stuff");" onkeypress="onmouseup()">
```

Since I can't grab this element by id, I have the following code to select it.

```
For Each item As Object In ie.document.getelementsbytagname("div")
    If item.getAttribute("title").Equals("myApp") Then
        item.click()
    End If
Next
```

The code executes fine, but it doesn't trigger the onmouseup() event with item.click(). Anyone know how I can go about triggering this?

Comment: There's no click handler attached to the `div`. `click()` triggers `onclick` only, it doesn't emulate `onmouseup`.

Comment: Alright that explains why it isn't working. Is there any way I might be able to trigger onmouseup?

Comment: Why not to attach a click handler too? Just in the same way you've attached an `onkeypress`.

Comment: I don't have the ability to change the html of the page unfortunately...

Comment: `item.onclick = item.onmouseup`?

Comment: Thanks Teemu, so simple.

Comment: Please add the solution mentioned and mark it as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `item.onclick = item.onmouseup` before `item.click()` as Teemu suggested worked perfectly.